# How can I get a tag type with a MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

```
        let mObserver = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
            mutationsList.forEach((mutation) => {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
                    mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
                        console.log(node)
                    })
                }
            })
        })

        mObserver.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        })
```

How can I tell the type of `node` that was added? I want to target only `a` tags

Comment: It makes it easier to see what is available if you use `console.dir`. It will always list the properties of what you are logging regardless of its type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName)

```
if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    // Do things
}
```